# В пределах какой сети работают сокеты

Tags: java, сеть, сокеты

Были попытки соединения сервера с клиентом через сокеты (Я использую Java), однако подключение получилось только тогда, когда и клиент и сервер находились в пределах одной Wi-fi сети. Возможно это глупый вопрос, но ответа в Интернете мне найти не удалось: можно ли осуществить возможность подключения к другому устройству в пределах всей сети Интернет с помощью сокетов? Если нет, то чем можно это осуществить? Спасибо

Comment: Конечно возможно, если на устройстве этот самый интернет корректно настроен и IP-адреса рабочие

Comment: вы задаете не те вопросы. Сокеты - это только способ обмена информацией. Если есть 2 устройства и между ними может быть установлено подключение, то тогда можно испольщовать сокеты для передачи данных. Если же есть просто 2 устройства в сети, но у них нет своего IP в их общей сети, то тогда просто нет технической возможности в принципе что то послать от одного устройства другому.

Comment: @tym32167, дело в том, что IP известен, он есть, но он виден только в локальной сети. Я поискал в интернете, и нашёл что-то про NAT, пока не разобрался в этом, но думаю что иду правильно

Comment: Почитайте еще про типы подсетей